# Is it possible to redirect the Windows API 'tmpfile' function?

Tags: windows, administrator, dll, temporary-files

We work with a 3rd-party tool for a software build that makes use of the [`tmpfile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tmpfile?view=msvc-160) function. As security has tightened and the ability for us to run tools as an administrator is removed, we're wondering if there is a workaround for running a tool like this without administrator rights. We've considered elevated accounts for running specific builds, but this is the only tool that really needs it. Is it possible to hook the `tmpfile` function using an alternate DLL or some other method? We have no control over the source code of this tool, nor are we able to use a different tool at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the tool has its own temporary folder that it insists upon,
the temporary folder's location is passed in the environment variables
of the program.

These are the
Windows TEMP/TMP Environment Variables.
TEMP is more for Windows internal programs and TMP is for user programs.
If in doubt, set both to the same value.
Logout/login is required for this to take effect.

For more details see the article
[Where Does Windows Store Temporary Files and How to Change TEMP Folder Location?](https://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/)

---

Specifically for the
[tmpfile function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tmpfile?view=msvc-160),
Microsoft apparently didn't update it after the writing in `C:\`
has become restricted to programs running with Administrator
permissions.

I would therefore advise running your program in a disk other than
`C:`. If your computer doesn't have a second disk, you may reduce
an existing partition, create a new one and call it `D:`.
If you don't have the permissions for that, use a partition editor
that is run from a boot media, if you have physical access to the computer. You may also run it from some external disk.

Any other solution would entail the replacement of the
tmpfile function by hooking this API, if this function is used
from a Windows DLL and is not statically linked into the
program. This requires good Windows programming knowledge.

Comment: Unfortunately the `tmpfile` function (which is noted as deprecated in the API docs) ignores the TEMP/TMP environment variables, and always creates a file in the root of the drive in which the System32 folder is found (IE, C:\). From the API documentation for `tmpfile`: The tmpfile function creates a temporary file and returns a pointer to that stream. The temporary file is created in the root directory. To create a temporary file in a directory other than the root, use tmpnam or tempnam in conjunction with fopen.

Comment: I see that this ancient function hasn't been updated by Microsoft. I have added more information to the answer about your options.

Comment: That seems promising - I'll give that a shot and accept the answer if that pans out. Although we have some folks with Windows programming knowledge I wasn't a fan of having to go down the route of hooking the API call. I'm also going to see if Windows treats a mapped drive equivalently (IE, map `C:\Test` to `D:` instead of creating a partition).

Comment: This did the trick. We were also able to map a drive letter and use it that way to avoid having to create a partition on our build machine just for this tool.